# Ruby on Rails blog application posts display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if there's a way to display both my last post created and also the latest three post created in the same page.

So this is how it looks now.what I want is to keep the left column like it is,but on the right column I want my last 3 posts to be displayed:
[image]

In my welcome_controller.rb I have this index method defined `@post =Post.limit(1).order("created_at desc")`that limits the posts to one but if I change it to 3 it applies to both left and right column and I get this really ugly thing]:

[image]

Comment: Please state the question involving code, not images. Also please put clearly what is the problem and what have you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your data in the action, like

```
@created_post     = Post.limit(1).order("created_at desc")
@last_three_posts = Post.limit(3).order("created_at desc")
```

and change your view accordingly but the created post will always be in the last three so you could use just `@last_three_posts`

```
@last_three_posts = Post.limit(3).order("created_at desc")
@created_post     = @last_three_posts.first
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve last 3 posts by this query

```
@posts =  Post.last(3)
```